# PFX encoded and back to PFX in Powershell

Tags: powershell, pfx

Is it possible when you convert a PFX to lets say Base64, to then convert it back to PFX ?

```
$PFX_FILE = get-content 'dummy.pfx' -Encoding Byte
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($PFX_FILE)) | Out-File 'dummy.txt'
$BASE64_STR = get-content 'dummy.txt' -Encoding utf8
[Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($BASE64_STR)) | Out-File 'dummy-2.pfx'
```

The output of line four is unsurprisingly invalid, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Base64 was made for this purpose - encode a binary file to be transferred as text and convert back to binary file later. `UTF8.GetBytes` doesn't make any sense though. You want to treat the .pfx file as binary instead of interpreting it as UTF-8 encoded. I suggest you get base64 encoding working first and compare the output with that of a tool that converts to base64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a PFX cert in location : C:\temp\PowerShellGraphCert.pfx and ran the following. I believe this is what you are looking for.
I converted > PowerShellGraphCert.pfx to PowerShellGraphCert.txt and then back to dummy-3.pfx.
**Now PowerShellGraphCert.pfx = dummy-3.pfx**

```
$PFX_FILE = get-content 'C:\temp\PowerShellGraphCert.pfx' -Encoding Byte
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PFX_FILE) | Out-File 'C:\temp\PowerShellGraphCertbase64.txt'

$BASE64_STR = get-content 'C:\temp\PowerShellGraphCertbase64.txt'
$filename = 'C:\temp\dummy-3.pfx'
$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($BASE64_STR)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
```

[image]

Comment: I still get a "invalid public key security object file" error when I try to open the generated PFX.

Comment: sorry got a little carried away. I have edited my code. it should not give you an error anymore. I believe this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeap, seems to work :) Thank you!
Wouldn't it be more consistent to use ReadAllBytes instead of -Encoding Byte or does it not work the same way ?